# React JS in HTML

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am totally new to React JS or any given server-side technology. And now, I want to learn how to develop in React JS.

**Introduction**

I started with React JS [tutorials](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html) on official website. Now, I am trying to import [React toolbox](http://react-toolbox.com/#/components) or any other third-party component into my JSX code. But, I am facing the problem of `uncaught exception error: require not defined`.

When I searched about it, I came to know about various build mechanisms(browserify, webpack, gulp), to which I was totally new(again). After reading about these, and seeing [some](https://github.com/DavidWells/isomorphic-react-example) [examples](https://github.com/mhart/react-server-example), I was able to let my browser compile `require()` statements written in my `.jsx` files.

**Problem**

What I am trying to do is:

- Write a `.html` file.
- Start it via my `server.js` file.
- Add a `<script>` tag in it, which will inject my `.jsx` code into my `.html` file.

The examples that I have seen so far ([1](https://github.com/DavidWells/isomorphic-react-example), [2](https://github.com/mhart/react-server-example), and some other...) load a `.js` file in the beginning and write their `.html` code in `.jsx` files (`render()` function).

**Question**

Is it possible to load a `.html` file from `server.js` and use `.jsx` from a `<script>` tag in that `.html` file? Something like this:

```
<html>
.
.
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="path_to_reactjs_file"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am sorry if this sounds like totally dumb question, but because of being totally new to this technology, I am not able to understand how I should go about it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like there might be an issue with file name extensions, Browserify only understands `.js` and `.json` extensions, unless you tell it otherwise.

`$ browserify --extension jsx src/main.js > bundle.js`

Babel with the right transforms will automatically do this for you as part of its module transpilation.

`$ browserify src/main.js -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ] > bundle.js`

Note that this assumes your entry point has a `.js` file extension, if it was `.jsx` you'd have to set the extension type.

This config can be simplified by adding the config to your `package.json`

```
{
  babel: {
    presets: [ 'es2015', 'react' ]
  }
},
{ 
  browserify: {
    transform: 'babelify'
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I have `.html` file as entry point? That is what I really wanna do. Use html file as entry point, and then use `.jsx` scripts in it.

Comment: No, that actually makes no sense :) Browserify and babel and other such tools are simply preparing your JS for the browser. The html 'houses' the scripts (if you will), React and many other libraries then work by creating more html and injecting it into the dom.

Comment: Oh, ok. I will accept your answer if something doesn't show up in 1 or 2 days. If you have a link to good tutorial, from where a total beginner(me) can start learning React, please let me know. Since what facebook told was totally unhelpful for absolute beginners. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Though, another related questions is, if I already have readymade html template, and now I want to go in react js, will I have to write all of that in `.jsx` files? What I was thinking is, you can use react scripts same as you can use javascript scripts in html.

Comment: You can, they just need a compile (or build) step as they are not js, they contain a separate language, so your browser does not understand them. Additionally, many times they use ES6 features and a module system, all of which your browser does not understand, so you have to build them into a version of JS they _do_ understand. This isnt a React problem. Most React starter-kits I've found arent easy to understand! [This](https://github.com/pheuter/essential-react) one looks fairly straight forward, maybe that can help you?

Comment: [this also looks good](https://reactforbeginners.com/), particularly if you like videos. I have not watched them but Wes Bos writes generally excellent stuff, and the first vid there sounds like it probably answers all your questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105374/discussion-between-droiddev-and-matt-styles).

Answer (score 0):

Without bundling, you can not include `jsx` to html directly, but you can create components without `jsx` syntax (use plain js) and it will work.

Comment: Actually, you can, if you additionally include the [JSX Transformer](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html#jsxtransformer) (or its Babel equivalent) to compile your script when it hits the browser. It certainly is not recommended for production (or even dev!) environments, but it makes sense for quick prototypes.

Comment: I tried using babel or JSX Transformer(through script tag in head) @MattStyles . It works fine until I am developing everything in `.jsx`. But, when I use `require()` statement or `import` statement in that, it gives me error(as I wrote in Introduction part)

Comment: Oh, it  sounds like a file name problem. Browserify's `require` algorithm (basically, node's) only understands `.js` and `.json` files, you have to explicitly tell it to import files with `.jsx`, I'll write up an answer as that sounds like it might be your issue.

Comment: My bad. I wasn't aware of that. I though that is was removed, but [babel-standalone](https://github.com/Daniel15/babel-standalone) might be good.

Answer (score 0):

**first thing to note...**

Browser can understand only HTML, CSS and plain javascript.

If you are providing JSX to browser, it fails to parse it. So you need to use a package bundler such as webpack. this converts all your JSX, typescript, Sass files into javascript(bundle.js) file. You can give this bundle.js file in the .html file